# Delete Firestore documents based on where condtiion

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase's Cloud FireStore for Flutter, I can delete a document based on it's ID value as below and it works fine.

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("newsfeed")
    .document(post.uid)
    .delete();
```

But I want to search a collection based on a field and delete all the matching documents.

I can get something based on the `where` condiation like below. But I am not sure how do I delete all the result documents.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> feedSnapShot = Firestore.instance
    .collection('newsfeed')
    .where('type', isEqualTo: type)
    .snapshots();
```

Comment: The advice in the dup is the same for all platforms, including Flutter.  You have to iterate the documents in the result and delete individually.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question is for Flutter and NOT JavaScript.

Comment: No emthods found for deletion for a DocumentReference of a FiresStore Beta.

Comment: Ok . Got it. Thanks.